# How can I set and read session data in RingoJS?

Tags: rhino, ringojs

Good day,

I have recently started playing with [RingoJS](http://ringojs.org/) along with [Stick middleware](https://github.com/hns/stick) and I am now stuck with sessions. I can't make it work.

**main.js**

```
var {Application} = require( "./_lib_/stick" ),
    app = exports.app = Application();

app.configure( "mount" );
app.mount( "/", require( "./actions" ) );

if ( require.main === module ) {
    require( "ringo/httpserver" ).main( module.directory );
}
```

**actions.js**

```
var {Application, helpers} = require( "./_lib_/stick" ),
    Response = require( "ringo/jsgi/response" );

export( "app" );

var app = Application();

app.configure( "route", "render", "session" );
app.render.base = module.resolve( "templates" );
app.render.master = "page.html";

app.get("/session.htm", function( request ) {
    //request.session.data.foo = "bar";
    request.session.data.put("foo", "bar");

    return Response.redirect( "session2.htm" );
});

app.get("/session2.htm", function( request ) {
    var value = request.session;

    return Response.html( "Session: " + value );
});
```

I've tested many combinaison but none of them worked as espected.

Most errors I get is about reading the data from the session. For example:

**TypeError: Cannot read property "data" from undefined**

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"session"` needs to come before `"mount"` in `app.configure`.

On the fourth line of main.js:

```
app.configure( "session", "mount" );
```

Then, remove `"session"` from the later call to `app.configure` since there's no point in running the middleware twice.

Comment: Actually, declaring session BEFORE mount did work: `app.configure( "session", "mount" );`. Update your answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you already had it in there. That makes sense.